# pygame image transparency not showing

Tags: python, image, pygame

I used a graphic routine to draw and image on grabbed it as an image as shown below.

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == UPDATE:

        y += 1

        get_image = screen.subsurface(60, 62, 82, 70)
        get_image.set_colorkey( (0,0, 0), RLEACCEL )
        if imageno <= 9:
            st = "0" + str(imageno)
        else:
            st = str(imageno)

        pygame.image.save(get_image, "graphicstest\\" + "mojo" + st + ".png")

        imageno += 1
```

But when I load an image with

```
img=pygame.image.load(path).convert.alpha()
```

and blit to screen the black area of the image shows. It is NOT transparent.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your convert_alpha() to just convert(), then the colorkey should work. If it doesn't, take away the RLEACCEL.

I just came across this same issue last night. I was using convert_alpha() on my images along with colorkey, and my images still had their undesired background. Changing to just convert() solved it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which I accept. I too figured it out just now. :)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem.
I removed the line `get_image.set_colorkey( (0,0, 0), RLEACCEL )`
from the code block where I grab the image.

Then I loaded it with `img=pygame.image.load(path`.
Did `img.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.Surface.convert_alpha(img)`

This worked perfectly.